# Reusing MArray instances for a newtype

Tags: haskell, typeclass, newtype, deriving

I have a dozen of newtypes like this:

```
newtype MyBool = MyBool Bool
newtype MyInt  = MyInt  Int
```

I want to reuse existing instances:

```
instance MArray IOUArray Int IO         where ...
instance MArray (STUArray s) Int (ST s) where ...
```

Implementing these instances and have all the boilerplate code is the last thing I want.

I found something that looks very close to what I am trying to achieve:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, StandaloneDeriving #-}

deriving instance MArray IOUArray MyInt IO      
deriving instance MArray (STUArray s) MyInt (ST s)
```

However, it fails with:

```
Can't make a derived instance of ‘MArray IOUArray MyInt IO’
    (even with cunning GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving):
    cannot eta-reduce the representation type enough
In the stand-alone deriving instance for ‘MArray IOUArray MyInt IO’
```

How to make this work?

If not possible, what is the least painful way to get those instances?

Comment: I tried to use safe coercions to generate the instance, but unfortunately we have `type role IOUArray nominal nominal` so we can't coerce from array-of-int to array-of-myint. (I wonder why we have such roles.)

Comment: Apparently it was [done this way](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/9220) in part to allow newtypes to use a different `Storable` instance for their unboxed representations (e.g., using a shorter-than-`Int` integer to store unboxed `newtype Age = Age Int`).

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving):

> We can even derive instances of multi-parameter classes, provided the newtype is the last class parameter.

> Notice also that the *order* of class parameters becomes important, since we can only derive instances for the last one. If the `StateMonad` class above were instead defined as
>
> ```
> class StateMonad m s | m -> s where ...
> ```
>
> then we would not have been able to derive an instance for the `Parser` type above. We hypothesise that multi-parameter classes usually have one “main” parameter for which deriving new instances is most interesting.

Since the last class parameter in your case isn't `Int`/`MyInt`, but rather `IO`/`ST s`, you're out of luck with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you're kind of stuck here because some design choices in the `array` package have made it difficult, but here's one approach that may help minimize boilerplate.

You can introduce a type family to map your newtypes to their underlying representation:

```
type family UType e where
  UType MyBool = Bool
  UType MyInt = Int
  UType a = a    -- default for built-in types
```

and then introduce newtype variants of the `IOUArray` and `STUArray` array types:

```
newtype NTSTUArray s i e = NTSTUArray (STUArray s i (UType e))
newtype NTIOUArray i e = NTIOUArray (IOUArray i (UType e))
```

and use *THESE* to get appropriate `MArray` instances for your new types:

```
instance (MArray (STUArray s) (UType e) (ST s), Coercible e (UType e))
       => MArray (NTSTUArray s) e (ST s) where
  getBounds (NTSTUArray arr) = getBounds arr
  getNumElements (NTSTUArray arr) = getNumElements arr
  newArray (a,b) e = NTSTUArray <$> newArray (a,b) (coerce e)
  newArray_ (a,b) = NTSTUArray <$> newArray_ (a,b)
  unsafeNewArray_ (a,b) = NTSTUArray <$> unsafeNewArray_ (a,b)
  unsafeRead (NTSTUArray arr) i = coerce <$> unsafeRead arr i
  unsafeWrite (NTSTUArray arr) i e = unsafeWrite arr i (coerce e)

instance (MArray IOUArray (UType e) IO, Coercible e (UType e))
       => MArray NTIOUArray e IO where
  getBounds (NTIOUArray arr) = getBounds arr
  getNumElements (NTIOUArray arr) = getNumElements arr
  newArray (a,b) e = NTIOUArray <$> newArray (a,b) (coerce e)
  newArray_ (a,b) = NTIOUArray <$> newArray_ (a,b)
  unsafeNewArray_ (a,b) = NTIOUArray <$> unsafeNewArray_ (a,b)
  unsafeRead (NTIOUArray arr) i = coerce <$> unsafeRead arr i
  unsafeWrite (NTIOUArray arr) i e = unsafeWrite arr i (coerce e)
```

Now, you should be able to use `NTIOUArray` and `NTSTUArray` in place of the usual `IOUArray` and `STUArray` for both built-in and your newtype element types:

```
main = do
  x <- newArray (1,10) (MyInt 0) :: IO (NTIOUArray Int MyInt)
  y <- newArray (1,10) 0         :: IO (NTIOUArray Int Int)
  readArray x 5 >>= writeArray y 8 . coerce
```

Any `IArray` instances can be generated automatically using `via` deriving (which works because the element type is the last argument to the `IArray` constraint):

```
deriving via MyBool instance IArray UArray MyBool
deriving via MyInt instance IArray UArray MyInt
```

or you could use the same technique above with an `NTIArray` newtype.

Some sample code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving,
    MultiParamTypeClasses, StandaloneDeriving, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Coerce (coerce, Coercible)
import Data.Array.Base
import Data.Array.IO
import Control.Monad.ST (ST)

newtype MyBool = MyBool Bool deriving (Show)
newtype MyInt = MyInt Int deriving (Show)

-- newtype arrays
type family UType e where
  UType MyBool = Bool
  UType MyInt = Int
  UType a = a
newtype NTSTUArray s i e = NTSTUArray (STUArray s i (UType e))
newtype NTIOUArray i e = NTIOUArray (IOUArray i (UType e))

deriving via MyBool instance IArray UArray MyBool
deriving via MyInt instance IArray UArray MyInt

instance (MArray (STUArray s) (UType e) (ST s), Coercible e (UType e))
       => MArray (NTSTUArray s) e (ST s) where
  getBounds (NTSTUArray arr) = getBounds arr
  getNumElements (NTSTUArray arr) = getNumElements arr
  newArray (a,b) e = NTSTUArray <$> newArray (a,b) (coerce e)
  newArray_ (a,b) = NTSTUArray <$> newArray_ (a,b)
  unsafeNewArray_ (a,b) = NTSTUArray <$> unsafeNewArray_ (a,b)
  unsafeRead (NTSTUArray arr) i = coerce <$> unsafeRead arr i
  unsafeWrite (NTSTUArray arr) i e = unsafeWrite arr i (coerce e)

instance (MArray IOUArray (UType e) IO, Coercible e (UType e))
       => MArray NTIOUArray e IO where
  getBounds (NTIOUArray arr) = getBounds arr
  getNumElements (NTIOUArray arr) = getNumElements arr
  newArray (a,b) e = NTIOUArray <$> newArray (a,b) (coerce e)
  newArray_ (a,b) = NTIOUArray <$> newArray_ (a,b)
  unsafeNewArray_ (a,b) = NTIOUArray <$> unsafeNewArray_ (a,b)
  unsafeRead (NTIOUArray arr) i = coerce <$> unsafeRead arr i
  unsafeWrite (NTIOUArray arr) i e = unsafeWrite arr i (coerce e)

main = do
  x <- newArray (1,10) (MyInt 0) :: IO (NTIOUArray Int MyInt)
  y <- newArray (1,10) 0         :: IO (NTIOUArray Int Int)
  readArray x 5 >>= writeArray y 8 . coerce
  x' <- freeze x :: IO (UArray Int MyInt)
  y' <- freeze y :: IO (UArray Int Int)
  print $ (x' ! 5, y' ! 8)

foo :: ST s (NTSTUArray s Int MyInt)
foo = newArray (1,10) (MyInt 0)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate `Okay, you're kind of stuck here because some design choices in the array package have made it difficult.`? I do not understand what goes wrong with deriving and what the following error means.
`
Can't make a derived instance of ‘MArray IOUArray MyInt IO’
    (even with cunning GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving):
    cannot eta-reduce the representation type enough
In the stand-alone deriving instance for ‘MArray IOUArray MyInt IO’
`